# Micro dsl for arithmetic in Ruby

Tags: ruby, dsl, irb

I want to write a tiny DSL in ruby for simple arithmetic.  It would look something like this:

```rb
whats 1 + 1
=> 2

whats 2 * 2
=> 4
```

The use case is teaching my child to program. I was showing her basic programming with `irb`, and when I gave her the keyboard she typed "whats 2 + 2" - possible in ruby?

Comment: If it's simple arithmetic expressions, you can build a parser pretty quickly.  I suggest not using eval for the math portion.

Comment: So your suggestion is to create an mini-REPL that parses a string expression, rather than something like `def whats(num1, op, num2)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it's quite simple:

```
def whats expr; expr end

whats 1 + 1
# => 2
```

Comment: BTW, where can I learn more about how this works. This is not the sort of thing covered in most Ruby 101 tutorials (that I've found, anyway).

Comment: It is stated in many tutorials. Ruby inherits the idea from Lisp. The last evaluation is the returned value. That is it.

Comment: ...can you recommend one? There are a lot on teh Intarwebs.

Comment: Also, I meant: what are the syntax rules for `1 + 1` being passed to the function as `expr`? In Clojure (the lisp I use), it would be `(defn whats [& [num1 op num2]] (eval (op num1 num2)))`

Comment: @noahlz `f 1 + 1` = `f(1 + 1)` given `f` is a method.

Answer (score 1):

What you want can’t be done all that elegantly because of Ruby’s operator precedence. In other words, because `whats 1 + 1` is the same as `whats(1 + 1)` (and `whats(2)`), the `whats` method has no idea that an operation occurred in its arguments.

You’ll have to override `Fixnum#+` (and any other operators) to return some sort of builder object. For example:

```
MathQuery = Struct.new(:left, :operator, :right)

class Fixnum
  def + other
    MathQuery.new(self, :+, other)
  end
end
```

Then `1 + 1` would return a MathQuery instance, which `whats` would receive and know how to handle.

Of course, the problem with this is that you’d need to somehow also make normal math operations still work, since lots of code obviously expects them to. Not quite sure how to pull that off, though. Maybe if everything always coerced with `to_int`, etc.…

In which case you might be better off writing an actual mini-language and parser using something like [Treetop](https://github.com/nathansobo/treetop).

Comment: Ok, this was the sort of answer I was expecting for an admittedly open-ended, large topic. Thanks!

Comment: Twist! See @sawa's answer.

Comment: @noahlz Well, sure, but given your [other comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17517255/micro-dsl-for-arithmetic-in-ruby/17517656#comment25470603_17517369) I assumed you wanted more information than just the result of the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Write a method called 'whats', accept any number of arguments, match the operator portion(s), and proceed.

Comment: I guess my question then is: is it possible to pass `+` as a an argument in ruby?

Comment: I guess then if the question is different, you may want to show some code that you have done, and show where you are having difficulty.  The thing is there are many ways that you can attack the issue.  But, use case, maybe.  case argument_2 ; when '+' then argument_1.to_i.+(argument_3.to_i);end